# JideTabbedPane close button color

Tags: colors, tabs, jide

I am using JideTabbedPane and i have the close button displayed using the following:

```
myTabbedPane.setShowCloseButtonOnTab(true);
```

The problem is my tabbedpane's theme is a dark color and the "X" close button is an "X" which is black in color. The color of my tabs are set using the "ColorProvider", but i don't see anything in the documentation mentioning changing the color of the close button.

Answer (score 0):

That property set in [BasicJideTabbedPaneUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGcNW.jpg) :

```
protected Color _closeButtonSelectedColor;
protected Color _closeButtonColor;
```

If you want change color of this button you should set new Color via UIDefaults or modify existing code in  https://www.javatips.net/api/jide-oss-master/src/com/jidesoft/swing/JideTabbedPane.java